# Angular Tutorial; can't read from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I'm doing the angular tutorial and I'm up to a step where I'm dynamically make a list. But when I try to make the list of items, the items won't come up

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\app.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js\controllers.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span2">
    <!--Sidebar content-->

    Search: <input ng-model="query">

  </div>
  <div class="span10">
    <!--Body content-->

   <ul class="phones">
      <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query">
        {{phone.name}}
        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

the Javascript

```
 'use strict';

 /* Controllers */

 var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

 $phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.phones = [
 {'name': 'Nexus S',
  'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
 {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
  'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
{'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
  'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

I originally thought it was a location problem but the location is right, I usually have problems importing javascript and I usually code the javascript on the same page but I'm trying to stop that habit. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a `$` before this line:

```
$phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function PhoneListCtrl($scope)
```

You want:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function PhoneListCtrl($scope)
```

Here's a working fiddle with this change:  http://jsfiddle.net/rbQry/

Edit: Sounds also like this `<script>` not point to angular:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Try instead using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: hmm weird I did all the changes and I still don't get the items of the list

Comment: Did you get the changes by @ozandlb and @tymeJV?  Those wouldn't show up in the fiddle since it handles the includes itself

Comment: yes I did, when I an the console is said something like Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Good team effort.  You can switch back to a local copy at some point if you want, you'll just need to figure out where it lives in your directory structure.  Or using the CDN is fine- it's generally even better when you're in production.

Comment: how did you find that cdn btw? I'm actually encountering a similar problem again

Comment: Go to angularjs.com and click on "download".  The third option down is "CDN:".  Just copy from that and you'll be set.

Answer (score 2):

Slash is going the wrong way

```
"js\controllers.js"
```

to

```
"js/controllers.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to responses by tymeJV, 11684 and KayakDave,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\app.css">
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

tymeJV is probably correct, but I spotted something else.

You first initialize your app like this:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
```

But then, you try to reference it as `$phonecatApp`, which is, (from JS' perspective) something completely unrelated: a non-initialized (and non-declared) symbol. By removing the `$` sign (and changing that slash) you should be fine.

A note: this kind of errors can be catched real easy with the console. In browsers like Firefox, Chrome and Safari (*not* IE) you can ctrl-click (or right-click for Windows) somewhere on the page which will bring up the `inspect element` pane (which is very useful as well). There should be an option `console`. If you click it you find a REPL for JavaScript and a list of all occured errors, complete with line number.

Ah, it seems KayakDave beat me. I'll leave the answer here for the note.

Comment: oh thankts for the tips, but still doesn't work. when I ran the console is said something in my javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined, not sure what it means.

Comment: Make sure your angular is really at: lib/angular/angular.js  or try just getting it from the CDN: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>

Comment: @user2809321 Have you changed that slash already? Are you sure that file is really there on your filesystem?